# Why did I get Lord of Wolves from Xur?

Tags: destiny-2

I just got Lord of Wolves exotic shotgun from Xur’s engram. Do believe the this is supposed to be unavailable from engrams, just spider bounties. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was added to Xur's loot pool when Season of the drifter came out in April of last year.